# I am attempting to group-by ID and sort by date within each group to find the time between events

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Here is an example data frame to recreate the data I am working with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {
'id': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4],
'date': ['2017-01-09', '2017-01-19', '2017-01-20', '2017-01-21', '2017-01-26', '2017-01-30', '2017-02-07', '2017-02-10', '2017-02-13', '2017-02-15', '2017-02-20', '2017-02-21'],
'event': ['A','A','B','A','A','A','B','A','B','A','A','B']
} )
```

What I am attempting to do is group-by 'id', however, using the grouby method is not actually grouping records by id:

`df = df.groupby(['id'])`

Furthermore, I would like to sort by date within each group and then create a new column for the number of days between event 'B' and the most recent event 'A' prior to event 'B' within each group.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

*Edit* - I would expect the output to look something like this example: http://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Group-a-dataframe-in-python-pandas-%E2%80%93-group-by-function-in-pandas-4.png

Comment: Could you also add the expected output sample from your given input?

Comment: Please see the link I provided for an example.  I would expect to have ID grouped in a similar manner as Subject is grouped in the image. I would then like to sort by date and be able to identify the number of days between event 'B' and the most recent event 'A' prior to event 'B' within each group.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution below, but I think there should be an efficient way to solve it.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df.groupby("id").apply(
    lambda x: x.loc[x['event']=='B', 'date'] - x.loc[(x['event']!='B')&(x['date'] <= x.loc[x['event']=='B', 'date'].values[0]), 'date'].max()
).reset_index(name='date_gap').drop(columns=['level_1'])
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is giving me an error:  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: @Jake Niederer, You should firstly make the date column to datetime type. I edit my answer.